# How to get specific div in div with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Does anyone know how to get the `div` using `for-loop`?

(carss and fun place for kids)

```
<div>
<div>Toy Shop</div>
<div>#03-538</div>
<div>Fun place for kids</div>

</div>


<div>
<div>car Shop</div>
<div>#01-342</div>
<div>carss</div>

</div>
```

I am trying to scrape the `div` content but does not know how to get content in `div` that does not have class or id.

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily. Take a minute to check - How to create [mcve] Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on little details from question you could use [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to select with pseudo classes `:last-child` or `:last-of-type`.

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
<div>
<div>Toy Shop</div>
<div>#03-538</div>
<div>Fun place for kids</div>
</div>

<div>
<div>car Shop</div>
<div>#01-342</div>
<div>carss</div>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for e in soup.select('div>div:last-child'):
    print(e.text)
```

##### Output

```
Fun place for kids
carss
```

Answer (score 0):

you should create a `BeautifulSoup` object, something like this

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

then you declare a function for finding all div elements

```
divs = soup.find_all('div')
```

and lastly i think you could iterate it through the  div elements using a for loop which kinda should look like this

```
for div in divs:
    print(div.text)
```

that should scrape the divs perhaps.

Comment: Do not think this will give only the expected strings, have you tested your approach?  *It is scrape, scraping, scraper - scrap is something completely different - For instructions on formatting and improving your answers take a read: How do I format my code blocks https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks?*